# Precedence constraints using binary variables - DOCPLEX

Tags: constraint, cplex, constraint-programming, or-tools, docplex

I would like to establish a precedence constraint to ensure the precedence relation of tasks. I have a set of tasks available, but required tasks are not always the same. It means, the tasks executed will depend of the demand.

When I searched for examples of precedence constraints in CPLEX/DOCPLEX and also OR-TOOLS, all examples I found use interval variables for establishing precedence constraints. In my case, I don't have interval variables, just binary ones.

I tried to implement the following precedence constraint:

```
  for t1 in required_tasks:
        for t2 in required_tasks:
            for w in range(1, len(task_cost) + 1):
                for j1 in range(1, number_tasks + 1):
                    for j2 in range(1, number_tasks + 1):
                        if j1 < j2:
                             if t2 in preced_task[t1]:
                                  opt_model.add(
                                        X[t1, w, j1] *
                                        precedence[t1, t2]
                                        >= X[t2, w, j2]
                                    )
```

*Some definitions:*

- `X` is a binary variable
- `w` is the worker index
- `t1` and `t2` are task indexes
- `j1` and `j2` are the positions of the tasks in the sequence
- `preced_task` is a dictionary containing the precedence relation.

Example: In this case, task 2 must be done after task 1, task 3 must be done after task 2. Task 1, 4, etc do not require any tasks before them.

```
preced_task = {1: [], 2: [1], 3: [2], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: []}
```

When I consider `j1` and `j2` in `range(1, number_tasks + 1)` it does not return a solution. However, if I consider `j1` and `j2` in `range(2, number_tasks + 1)` it returns a solution respecting precedence for one task (2, for example), but not for task 3.

Could someone help me with that?

Comment: Would you see the resources-constraint project schedule or other related scheduling problem such as flowshop? They contain task precedence constraints  (using binary variables) which  you could benchmark.

Comment: Your `preced_task` keys are (1, 2, ..) and I assume `X` index starts from 0. Are you sure then you're correctly indexing `X`? Also, this is just a suggestion about implementing your constraint. You have 5 loops and you only have a handful of values in `preced_task`. So, I suggest changing the order of your loops. Loop over your `preced_task` which gives you only those keys and values that you need and then for the desired `j1` and `j2` indices coming from `preced_task`, you can create your constraint.

Comment: @A.Omidi, thanks for replying. I took a look at the references you suggested me in another post (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3055/scheduling-with-transition-costs-docplex/3064#3064), but I was looking for some code examples. In the tutorial of Philippe Laborie he used interval variables to establish precedence constraints...

Comment: @EhsanK I'm not sure I understood your answer. `X` is a decision variable and its index is based on `t`, `w` and `j`. All of them start from 1.

Comment: @campioni I didn't know how you defined `x`. That was just a check to make sure the index problem is not coming from `x` being defined on a different range. Anyway, it seems you figured out a solution.

Comment: @campioni, I hope, [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jckantor/ND-Pyomo-Cookbook/blob/master/notebooks/04.02-Job-Shop-Scheduling.ipynb) or [this](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_HTML/2014/07/4442.html) links would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while, I finally found a way to establish a precedence constraint using binary variables. 
It was hard to find examples of precedence constraints that do not use time as a parameter in both theoretical models and also code implementation tutorials.

Anyway, I am sharing here the code I used in DOCPLEX to establish the precedence constraint with binary variable without using time, but just process plan position as a parameter. I hope it will help other people dealing with similar problems.

```
for t1 in required_tasks:
    for t2 in required_tasks:
        for j2 in range(1, number_tasks + 1):
            opt_model.add(
                opt_model.sum(
                    X_var[t1, w1, j1]
                    for w1 in range(1, len(workers) + 1)
                    for j1 in range(1, j2)
                )
                 >= opt_model.sum(
                    X_var[t2, w2, j2] * precedence[t1,t2]
                    for w2 in range(1, len(workers) + 1)

                )
            )
```

PS: precedence is a dictionary showing the precedence relation between `t1` and `t2`. If `t1` must be done before `t2`, `precedence[t1, t2] = 1`, and `0` otherwise.